# How to see the answers in Google Forms before submitting

Tags: google-forms

How is it possible to see the answers of a questionnaire in Google Forms, before sending it?

Could you use the Google Chrome item inspector?

Answer (score 1):

You can see your answers with Google Chrome's inspector or even without it. But there are no tools to see other people's answer or the "correct answer" if you aren't the owner.

Answer (score 1):

This trick only works when owner let you see the results right after the test.

1. Enter fake or random email adress and answer all the questions randomly
2. Then click on show result
3. Now you can see the correct and wrong answers.
4. Now answer with your original email adress.  .